# App can't find my App class? ClassNotFoundException for a few users

Tags: android

I've got an app with a few thousand downloads. I'm seeing this crash in the play developer console, but can't figure out how it could be happening:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Unable to instantiate application com.me.example.MyAppClass: 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.me.example.MyAppClass
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4201)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:140)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.me.example.MyAppClass
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:971)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
  ... 11 more
```

so it's saying it can't find my application class. It is defined like this in my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.example">

    <application
      android:name=".MyAppClass">
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The only thing I can think of is that the relative path style used in the  tag for MyAppClass is causing problems for some devices? This is working for 99% of my users.

I'm also using proguard. But if it were an obfuscation problem, I'd expect it to fail on any device.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Do you have any information about the kinds of devices this is failing on?

Comment: No, the play console just labels them as "OTHER".

Comment: it could be a hit and miss proguard problem. It happened with me before as well. This happens when the class is Obfuscated and the OS can't get to it since its obfuscated. Try keeping the class using the -keep attribute

Comment: @Amey shouldn't it fail on every device I run the apk on then if the obfuscation is the problem?